# F# Compiler Not Recognizing Type

Tags: f#

In this snippet, the current (4.1) compiler complains that it can't determine which overload to Convert to use (*a type annotation may be needed*), but it recognizes s as a string.  Why?

```
let wtf (list:string List) =  
  List.map (fun s -> System.Convert.ToInt32(s)) list
```

Comment: How do you know that it recognizes `s` as a string?

Comment: By hovering mouse over s.

Comment: I think maybe it's not the compiler that recognizes s as a string. The compiler is one-pass, so it can't see "list" at the end there. That's also why this works: `let wtf (li: string list) = li |> List.map Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: So... the type info in the hover text is unreliable and misleading?

Comment: @dudeNumber4 - That's basically right - IntelliSense uses some additional heuristics that the compiler itself does not use.

Comment: It's not "unreliable". Intellisense was never intended to mimic the compiler. Intellisense is there to _help you_.

Comment: Granted, intellisense is intended to help.  In this case, it mislead.  I'm coming at this from a practical standpoint; I've never experienced this in years of C# development.  I'd love to use F# in a practical way; I love the language.  Yet, you can see how these intricacies can be a barrier to adoption (pipe it in, pass it as a parameter, shouldn't they compile exactly the same?).  I'm not casting aspersions on F#, just stating practical matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler uses single pass over the code to determine the types. This means that it will report an error (e.g. when it cannot determine which overload to use) as it passes over the problematic code. If it later finds more information, the additional information is not used.

This is exactly what is happening here. Consider:

```
let wtf (list:string List) =  
  List.map (fun s -> s) list
```

Here, the type of `s` is `string` and everything works fine. However, when checking `fun s -> s`, the compiler does not yet know that the type of `s` is `string` and it treats it as a value of type variable `'a` - it checks the type of function as `'a -> 'a` and later unifies `'a` with `string`. Going back to your case:

```
let wtf (list:string List) =  
  List.map (fun s -> System.Convert.ToInt32(s)) list
```

When checking the lambda, the compiler knows `s` is of type `'a` and it fails to resolve the overload of `ToInt32`. It reports the error, skips the sub-expression and continues (to get as useful IntelliSense as it can) and it later figures out that `s` was actually `string`. This appears in the IntelliSense, but it does not undo the error.

Just for the record, the best way to avoid this is to use `|>` and put the `list` input first:

```
let awesome (list:string List) =  
  list |> List.map (fun s -> System.Convert.ToInt32(s))
```